Every regular, scattered and Lindelöf space with countable pseudocharacter has countable cardinality.
Let $(X, \tau)$ be a regular, scattered and Lindelöf space with countable pseudocharacter. Is it true that $X$ needs to be countable?
What I have tried (using the Theorem 2.2 from M. E. Gewand, “The Lindelöf degree of scattered spaces and their products,” Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society (Series A) 37 (1984), 98–105): Let $(X, \tau)$ be a regular scattered Lindelöf space with countable pseudocharacter.
(Before going on, $X_{\delta}$ denotes the topological space of $X$ with the topology generated by its $G_{\delta}$ sets under the topology $\tau$).
As a consequence of the Theorem 2.2 ($X$ is $T_3$, scattered and Lindelöf), $X_{\delta}$ is Lindelöf. Now, as each point of $X$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set, then $X_{\delta}$ is discrete and $\mathcal{A} = \{ \{x\} : x \in X \}$ is an open cover of $X_{\delta}$. Finally, as $X_{\delta}$ is Lindelöf, $X$ needs to be countable.

Was this your assumption, or did you find this as a statement / question somewhere?

I was reading the question from MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/416331 and the author said: "It is known that any first countable, T3, Lindelöf and scattered space is countable".
I wasn't aware of this result, so I tried to look for its proof and I found that it appears stated as the Corollary 2.5 (with a typo) in the citation I make in this question, but its proof would say that it's a consequence of the Theorem 2.2 from that same citation. In this question, I show my attempt to prove the corollary using the theorem, but I wanted to ask for clarifications or reviews and more direct proofs.

Thank you for your comment. About your question: yes, of course, your derivation of the corollary is correct. Moreover, PatrickR gave a direct proof.

You're welcome. Thank you too for the review.

Here is a direct proof.

Lemma: Every Lindelöf locally countable space is countable.

This is easy to check (for example see Must scattered spaces with points $G_\delta$ be locally countable?).

Theorem: Every regular Lindelöf scattered space with each point a $G_\delta$-set is countable.

Proof: Suppose $X$ is regular Lindelöf scattered and each point is a $G_\delta$-set.  Scattered spaces are $T_0$ (see here), and $T_0$ regular spaces are $T_3$.  So $X$ is Hausdorff and $T_1$.
Let $B$ be the set of points $x\in X$ at which $X$ is locally countable (i.e., such that $x$ has a countable nbhd).  The set $B$ is open in $X$.  So its complement $A=X\setminus B$ is closed, hence Lindelöf.  Suppose by contradiction that $A$ is not empty.  By the scattered property, there is a point $x\in A$ that is isolated in $A$.  So there is an open set $U\subseteq X$ with $U\cap A=\{x\}$.
Since the singleton $\{x\}$ is a $G_\delta$, we have $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ for some open sets $G_n\subseteq U$.  By regularity of $X$ we can also assume $\overline G_1\subseteq U$.
Each of the $\overline G_1\setminus G_n$ is closed in $X$, hence Lindelöf.  And it is also locally countable as a subset of the locally countable open set $U\setminus\{x\}\subseteq B$.  Thus $\overline G_1\setminus G_n$ is countable by the Lemma.  And since the set $G_1\setminus\{x\}$ is covered by these countably many countable sets, it is also countable.  But then $G_1$ is a countable nbhd of $x$,  which contradicts the fact that $x\in A$.  Therefore $A=\emptyset$ and $X$ is locally countable.  Finally, one more application of the Lemma shows that $X$ is countable.

Very nice proof (+1). I was just wondering whether regular can be weakened to Hausdorff. According to this paper it cannot!

This space https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000171 (which isn't regular) is functionally Hausdorff (so also Hausdorff), scattered, Lindelöf and with countable pseudocharacter, but it has uncountable cardinality.

@Ulli Thanks for the very interesting reference.

@Almanzoris: That's very strange: before finding the above cited paper, I also looked up pi-base with this query. But it didn't provide Brian's example, although it matches all criteria.

Yeah, it didn't provide it, because Brian's example didn't have the regular property included (as not being regular) in its properties list yet. This theorem has been added to pi-Base after the question has been answered and, as a result, Brian's example has got that deduced from it and from the other properties that it had already in its own list.

@Almanzoris: Brian's example is listed as non-regular (at least just now). However, the query still does not provide it.

@Ulli Have you synced the main branch in the advanced section of pi-Base??

@Almanzoris: ah, now I see it. I didn't know that one has to reset pi-base. Anyway, that I didn't see it in the beginning had the big advantage that I kept searching for examples and so found this quite interesting paper cited above. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR SUPPORT!

@Ulli jajaja, it also happened to me the first time. You're welcome. And thank you for having provided such rich paper. Have a great day, sir.

@Almanzoris fyi, I have asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4955301 for a related question.  It should be answerable with similar ideas.

Thank you for the information. Also, despite I hadn't said it yet, thank you for your great proof of your answer to this question, Patrick.
